# Can't understand the output of fork () when there is an exit(0) in the parent

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

When I run below program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
//multiple children of the same parent
void main(){
    int pid,i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        pid = fork();
        if(pid<0)
            printf("fork failed.");
        else if(pid>0){
            wait(NULL);
            printf("i =%d, Child has finished. I am the parent[PID=%d].\n",i,getpid());
            _exit(0);
        }
        else{
            printf("i = %d, pid =%d, I am the child[PID=%d],  parent[PID=%d] \n",i,pid, getpid(),getppid());
        }
    }
}
```

I got the following output:

```
i = 0, pid =0, I am the child[PID=7720],  parent[PID=7719] 
i = 1, pid =0, I am the child[PID=7721],  parent[PID=7720] 
i = 2, pid =0, I am the child[PID=7722],  parent[PID=7721] 
i =2, Child has finished. I am the parent[PID=7721].
i =1, Child has finished. I am the parent[PID=7720].
i =0, Child has finished. I am the parent[PID=7719].
```

However, I can’t understand the output.

If we trace the tree. Assuming that the parent represents the bash running this program.
So after fork we will have a child (call it C1) for that parent. The parent has to wait for it’s child because of the Wait(NULL) system call which is going to receive the SIGCHLD signal (PID) number returned by the child to the parent to terminate. Then another fork() has been done producing another child from (C2). However, there is no other child produced by the parent (C3) as in the normal case scenario without the exit(0) in the parent.

In this case n forks = n children (3 forks are going to produce only 3 children not 8). 
Can someone help me to understand why the there is no child (C3) for the parent (bash) since it was waiting for C1, so it didn’t exit from the program.

Comment: It is not clear from your description which part is confusing for you. P creates C1 and waits. C1 creates C2 and waits. C2 creates C3 and waits. C3 exits normally because the `for` is finished, at which point C2 calls `_exit(0)`, at which point C1 calls `_exit(0)`, at which point P calls `_exit(0)`. It P and C1 did not have the `_exit(0)` inside `else if(pid>0)`, they would span more children according to the `for` - two more for P and one more for C1.

Comment: Why there are no 8 children? why in the second fork C1 create C2 and waits and P didn't create another child because the fork() was for both C2 and P. I hope it's clear now

Answer (score 1):

Here's the walkthrough:

- Process P creates C1

  - Process P then blocks waiting for C1 [i=0]
- C1 prints the "I am the child" and loops back [i=1]
- C1 forks C2

  - C1 blocks waiting for C2
- C2 prints "I am the child" and loops back [i=2]
- C2 forks C3

  - C2 blocks waiting for C3
- C3 prints "I am the child" and *the loop terminates*
- C3 exits
- C2 unblocks, prints that C3 has exited and then itself exits
- C1 unblocks, prints that C2 has exited, and then exits
- P unblocks, prints that C1 has exited, then exits

There are not 8 children because the parent never finishes the full loop iteration except in the very last case.  Look at it from just process P's perspective:  you fork a child, wait for it to finish, and then exit.